# PayPal REST API returns INVALID_CURRENCY_AMOUNT_FORMAT

Tags: spring-boot, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

> response-code: 400 details: name: VALIDATION_ERROR message: Invalid request - see details  details: [{
>    "field": "transactions.amount",
>   "issue": "Cannot construct instance of `com.paypal.platform.payments.model.rest.common.Amount`, >problem: INVALID_CURRENCY_AMOUNT_FORMAT"
>   }] debug-id: 86ad5783892c3 information-link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors

```
package com.spring.soap.api;


@Configuration
public class PaypalConfig {

@Value("${paypal.client.id}")
   private String clientId;
@Value("${paypal.client.secret}")
   private String clientSecret;
@Value("${paypal.mode}")
   private String mode;
@Bean
public Map<String,String> paypalSdkConfig(){
    Map<String,String> configMap= new HashMap<>();
    configMap.put("mode",mode);
    return configMap;
    }
@Bean
public OAuthTokenCredential oAuthTokenCredential() {
    return new OAuthTokenCredential(clientId,clientSecret,paypalSdkConfig());

}

@Bean
public APIContext apiContext() throws PayPalRESTException {
    APIContext context = new APIContext(oAuthTokenCredential().getAccessToken());
    context.setConfigurationMap(paypalSdkConfig());
    return context;
}


}

{
@Autowired
PaypalService service;



public static final String SUCCESS_URL = "pay/success";
public static final String CANCEL_URL = "pay/cancel";

@GetMapping("/")
public  String home() {
    return "home";
}

@PostMapping("/pay")
public String payment(@ModelAttribute("order") Order order) {
    try {
        Payment payment = service.createPayment(order.getPrice(), order.getCurrency(), order.getMethod(),
                order.getIntent(), order.getDescription(), "http://localhost:9090/" + CANCEL_URL,
                "http://localhost:9090/" + SUCCESS_URL);
        for(Links link:payment.getLinks()) {
            if(link.getRel().equals("approval_url")) {
                return "redirect:"+link.getHref();
            }
        }

    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}
@GetMapping(value = CANCEL_URL)
public String cancelPay() {
    return "cancel";
}

@GetMapping(value = SUCCESS_URL)
public String successPay(@RequestParam("paymentId") String paymentId, @RequestParam("PayerID") String payerId) {
    try {
        Payment payment = service.executePayment(paymentId, payerId);
        System.out.println(payment.toJSON());
        if (payment.getState().equals("approved")) {
            return "success";
        }
    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return "redirect:/";
}


}

{
@Autowired
private APIContext apiContext;

public Payment createPayment(
        Double total, 
        String currency, 
        String method,
        String intent,
        String description, 
        String cancelUrl, 
        String successUrl) throws PayPalRESTException{
    Amount amount = new Amount();
    amount.setCurrency(currency);
    total = new BigDecimal(total).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
    amount.setTotal(String.format("%.2f", total));

    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setDescription(description);
    transaction.setAmount(amount);

    List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    transactions.add(transaction);

    Payer payer = new Payer();
    payer.setPaymentMethod(method);

    Payment payment = new Payment();
    payment.setIntent(intent);
    payment.setPayer(payer);  
    payment.setTransactions(transactions);
    RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
    redirectUrls.setCancelUrl(cancelUrl);
    redirectUrls.setReturnUrl(successUrl);
    payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);

    return payment.create(apiContext);
}

public Payment executePayment(String paymentId, String payerId) throws PayPalRESTException{
    Payment payment = new Payment();
    payment.setId(paymentId);
    PaymentExecution paymentExecute = new PaymentExecution();
    paymentExecute.setPayerId(payerId);
    return payment.execute(apiContext, paymentExecute);
}



}
```

Comment: Your question does not include a sample value of the string you are trying to set in the amount field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear your locale is formatting decimals with a comma (`,`) as the decimal separator.

The PayPal API exclusively accepts numbers with a period (`.`) as the decimal separator

Comment: Thanks, you are true

Answer (score 2):

Take this line:

```
amount.setTotal(String.format("%.2f", total));
```

Change `%.2f` to `%.3f`. The final code should look like:

```
amount.setTotal(String.format("%.3f", total));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was sending the SubTotal on Details with a NON rounded value:

```
141.750
```

So I just round the value like this:

```
details.setSubtotal(subTotal.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_EVEN).toString());
```

(In other words)

```
141.75
```